# Ignore SSH timeout to continue Gitlab CI

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using gitlab CI to deploy my project on virtuals machines through SSH. Some of virtuals machines can be off at the moment of my deploy so my job fail when I can't reach one of these vm.

Here what I'm doing in my ci

```
        - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@vm1 "mkdir -p /myproject/releases/$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
        - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@vm1 "mkdir -p /myproject/releases/$CI_COMMIT_TAG/dev"
        - rsync -az * user@vm1:/myproject/releases/$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

At the first ssh command, I have this error :

```
ssh: connect to host vm1 port 22: Connection timed out ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

How can I ignore SSH timeout to continue my gitlab ci ?

The best solution to me could be :

If the vm doesn't "answer" about 20 seconds, ignore it and try to deploy to the next vm.

Thank you very much :)

EDIT : I've got the same problem with rsync of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a `|| true` after each `ssh` to always return something which Travis will not interpret as an error, but would also wait until the command is done.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for my problem is a bash script.

1. ping the remote vm
2. if the vm answers to the ping : deploy